# How to Switch On or Switch Off a PC using android application

Tags: android

Can i know how to Switch on or Switch Off the PC remotely using android application.Also can we open or close any PC applications like(Paint,Notepad,etc..,)using android application.

Comment: use Telepathy Interface API ...

Comment: @Selvin can i have some tutorials...?

Comment: i think @Selvin have some tutorials for this Telepathy Interface API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have voted to close that question, here is some basic knowledge you need to even consider what you are trying to do:

1. if the PC is off, like in no power, there is no chance to get it to turn on remotely.
2. You could use [Wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). Details on how this works and why the PC (understood as the complete hardware) is not fully "off"
3. You need some kind of a "host" application that is started when the OS boots up. When you have contact with the PC over your application you might be able to start some applications (depends heavily on the OS the PC runs).
4. A free (for private usage) application is TeamViewer which allows you to control a PC from your Android device. It takes over the control of the input and therefore you have remote access to everything.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using a client - server application. The server is a Java based application that will run on the PC. The client will be your Android phone. They communication will be WI-FI based (it's difficult ) or Bluettoth based ( this is easier ). But be careful as the server application will need to have full administration rights to trigger some operations.

Comment: So the java application on the PC runs even when the PC is off? Nice...

Comment: @WarrenFaith atleast i need an example even to understand, I have googled but no use

Comment: @BMU is give u example to connected PC

Comment: @Vandana how about you start using the brain of yours? If the PC is off, there is no power, if there is no power there is no booted root OS, if there is no OS you can't have an application running...

Comment: @WarrenFaith , I assumed that the PC he is trying to control remotely is ON.

Comment: @BMU then it's pointless to turn it on, if it's already turned on

Comment: I just asked in a developer mind of way..Any way can i know how to switch off the pc atleast.

Comment: @BMU please don't assume when the question starts with `Can i know how to Switch on ...`